# Circular dependency in single C header file. Forward declaration needed?

Tags: c, struct

```
#ifndef STAGE_TABLE_DEFINITION_HEADER
#define STAGE_TABLE_DEFINITION_HEADER

typedef stage_table_context_t* (*stage_table_function_t)(stage_table_context_t*);

typedef struct {
    const char* stage_name;
    stage_table_function_t* function;
} stage_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t error_number;
    stage_t* current_stage;
} stage_table_context_t;

#endif
```

Getting an unknown type error on `stage_table_context_t`.

The function pointer `stage_table_function_t` refers to `stage_table_context_t` and `stage_table_context_t` refers to `stage_table_function_t`.

Obviously positioning doesn't matter here since either orientation will result in an issue. Seems I need to forward declare the stage table context structure, but not sure how to do this with a typedef.

Apologies for the stupid question, I've been away from C for 6 months and I'm having a bit of a brain fart.

edit: Fixed some typo's in the code.

Comment: Does `typedef struct stage_table_context_t* (*stage_table_function_t)(struct stage_table_context_t*);` work?

Comment: I am not getting any complaints from the compiler on that line other than the unknown type error.

Comment: Yes, a forward declaration is needed.  There are several ways to provide one.

Comment: You can't do it using two untagged (or tagless) structures.  At least one of them must have a tag; for symmetry, both should have a tag, therefore.  Then you can forward declare one or both structure types, and then define the structure types.  Again, symmetry suggests forward declaring both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the declaration of a `struct` before its definition:

```
/* declaration */
struct foo;

.....

/* definition */
struct foo
{
   ....
};
```

Anywhere you write `struct foo` is a declaration of the struct, so you don't have to put it in a separate line, you can have it in a typedef, pointer declaration, etc..
Just be aware that sometimes, like in variable declarations of type `struct foo` you also need the definition (to calculate the variable size);

```
/* declare struct foo ..*/   
struct foo;

/* .. or declare struct foo ..*/   
typedef struct foo foo;

/* .. or declare struct foo ..*/   
struct foo *p;   

/* .. or declare struct foo */   
int bar (struct foo *p);  

/* Not valid since we don't have definition yet */
struct foo f1;   

/* definition */
struct foo
{
   ....
};

/* Valid */
struct foo f2;
```

In your case you haven't given the struct a name; you've just made a `typedef` that is an alias for an anonymous struct. So to forward declare your struct you have to give it a name:

```
/* 
  forward declare the `struct stage_table_context_t` and give it a typedef alias
  with the same name as the structs name
*/ 
typedef struct stage_table_context_t stage_table_context_t;

typedef stage_table_context_t* (*stage_table_function_t)(stage_table_context_t*);

typedef struct {
    const char* stage_name;
    stage_table_function_t* function;
} stage_t;

struct stage_table_context_t{
    uint32_t error_number;
    stage_t* current_stage;
} stage_table_context_t;
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to tell the compiler that `stage_table_context_t` shall be a `struct`; by that, you implicitly forward-declare the `struct stage_table_context_t`, which's actual definition may then come later. Note that a typedef does not define a `struct`, it just introduces an alias. So the actual definition is `struct stage_table_context_t { ...`, regardless of whether you introduce an alias for it or not (and regardless of which name you use for the alias).

```
typedef struct stage_table_context_t* (*stage_table_function_t)(struct stage_table_context_t*);

typedef struct {
    const char* stage_name;
    stage_table_function_t* function;
} stage_t;

struct stage_table_context_t {
    uint32_t error_number;
    stage_t* current_stage;
};

// optional (if you want to use "stage_table_context_t" as an alias for "struct stage_table_context_t"):
typedef struct stage_table_context_t stage_table_context_t;
```

Comment: It's confusing to describe that as telling the compiler that the type will be a struct.  What's really happening would be clearer if you used a struct tag that differed from the typedef identifier: implicitly forward-declaring the struct type (which requires it to be tagged).  The coincidence between tag and typedef name is incidental.

Comment: Thanks this worked! What would the solution look like if I chose to emit the struct name during the structure typedef? (i.e. `typdef struct {`)

Comment: @SamD20, you cannot forward declare an untagged structure type.

Comment: @John Bollinger: thanks; edited the answer; hope it gets clearer now.

Comment: @SamD20 you can combine thins in one typedef, including fully defining a structure with name and even defining several type names in one go, i.e. `typedef struct mystructtag { member definitions } mystructtypedef, anothertypedefforthesamestructure, *typedefpointertothesamestructure;`

Comment: …but see [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) to which the short answer is "Usually no".